# how connect to local mysql server (LAN)

Tags: mysql, local-area-network

I got two Debian 6 servers - one for web and one for the database..

How can I connect through the local area network?

On both servers I have permanently changed the hostnames

```
/etc/hostname
/etc/hosts

web => web-server
db => db-server
```

In the privileges in mysql I have set the root user to accept requests from `web-server` (instead of localhost) and from the web-server I connect to `db-server`

in `my.cnf` I have escaped the following line:

```
# bind-address      = 127.0.0.1
```

## error

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'db-server' (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have in /etc/hosts ?

```
127.0.0.1 db-server
```

Cause of the comments, you will have to configure your LAN first.

Comment: yes... I'm sure :)

Comment: So you can do ping db-server and you get reply?

Comment: hmmm.. unknown host..?

Comment: Hmmmm so that's the problem. So you have a DB server in IP1 and a HTTP server in IP2 and you want to connect from HTTP server to DB server. That's alright?

Comment: yes.. correct..

Comment: Ok, so you have to put in **HTTP** server /etc/hosts: `ip-db-server db-server`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that your HTTP server has 192.168.1.1 for example and DB server has 192.168.1.2. So in your DB server /etc/hosts you have to have `192.168.1.1 web-server` and in your HTTP server `192.168.1.2 db-server` That way the server could resolve between themselves

Comment: ok.. and I get the LAN ip with `ifconfig`? is it the `bcast` address?

Comment: if there are on LAN you could get with `ifconfig`,yes. It's the **inet addr**. So if there are on LAN, pretty sure they will have a ip like 192.168.1.x

Comment: hmm.. there are only the inet address (internet IP) and 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: So you don't have the server in LAN.